# Best way to design Azure Functions to read events from more than one event hub

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I want to design azure functions in Python language to read events from more than one event hub . The number of event hubs are not constant , it can increase or decrease (for example one event hub publishes logs from one azure AD tenant and in future AD tenants can be added).  Each function will have same business logic ,only the even hub connection string will differ .

Event hub triggered function can use only one event hub , not more than more .

So, What is the best approach for this problem statement :

- Creating 1 Event hub triggered function for each event hub and keep all functions under one azure function APP and to have shared code which can be used by all functions .

  **Cons** : If a new event hub added , need to create a new function and deploy function standalone with Zero downtime of function APP ,which is not possible .As per [azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment) ,the deployment unit should be Function APP, not individual functions .
- Creating 1 function APP with single Event hub triggered function
  subscribing to one event hub .

  **Pros** As new function app is different for each event hub, if a
  new event hub added other function apps won't be impacted and zero
  downtime for them

  **Challenge** Assuming we have one Github repo with function
  logic, function.json , Is it possible to create a function app each
  time a new event hub added and create a deployment integrating with
  git repo. In future I want to use azure pipelines or Github actions
  for CI/CD , will this approach create any issue.

Comment: I'd probably build many AZ functions for each event hub and one main function that actually executes shared code which is called(orchestrated) by event hub triggered functions. Or logic apps even

Comment: @misha130 the challenge with creating new function for each event hub is if event hub is added we need to create a new function and we need to deploy the new function standalone without impacting other functions in function APP, which is not possible .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the business logic is exactly the same, then you can extract the core logic and put it in an http trigger function. You only need to [create multiple Azure logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow#create-your-logic-app) to [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs#add-event-hubs-trigger) and pass the content of the event hub to the [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps) for processing.

This way you don't have to worry about the downtime caused by multiple deployments, and I think it is easier to create multiple Azure logic apps than to create multiple Azure functions.

You can refer to my logic app design:

[image]